# Elementary on 2 in 1 laptops - Touch screen

Tags: laptop, software-recommendation, hp, touchscreen

I'm planning to buy a HP Pavilion X2 - 2 in 1 laptop.
It comes by default with Windows 10 - which is the system that convinced me to switch for Elementary ;)  - so naturally I'd like to work on Elementary.

However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use it as 'tablet' (It's still Computer, but with touch screen only). 
Is it possible to integrate Elementary with touch screen? If es then how? :)
I saw on youtube that someone did it with touchegg, but I've never used it before.

Comment: What do you want the touch screen to do? Out of the box mine works as as single touch = a left click. I can scroll up and down too.  Beyond that will require some setup.  Touchegg isn't compatible with loki unless you replace libinput with synaptics

Comment: I haven't been able to get the rotation function of my 2in1 to work. The rotation is always in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loki has compatibility with touchscreen, at least in my case (Asus X550C).
Just like you, I have Windows 10 installed along with Elementary. When I was in Freya, touchscreen was not supported and didn't work properly, but recently since I upgraded to Loki it works like a charm, just like in Windows. So yes, install Loki and you will be able to use the computer as a tablet.

Comment: Oh, ok, Thank you a lot! :D I was a bit frightened that I'll have to play with touchegg etc. But if Loki has touchscreen support, then I'm more than happy :D

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily.  I have tried Loki with two different 2in1 laptops.  On one, a Dell 3000 series, the touchscreen works, but rotation is buggy.  It always rotates into the wrong orientation, so it is totally unusable.  I also have an Asus Vivobook, and on that one, the rotation doesn't work at all, but at least it will orient to the normal, laptop direction.  I haven't tried getting the trackpad and keyboard lockup feature to work on my dell, but it doesn't work on the Asus, so I can't really use it in tablet mode.  So, I don't recommend Loki for 2in1 laptops.  It doesn't work on either of mine.

Answer (score 1):

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 5578 2in1, with Windows 10 and Loki, and it works ok as a tablet. I don't have auto rotation, but solved it with ScreenRotator. OnBoard works lovely, as an on-screen keyboard, too.